# set max-height of div doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to set a max-height on the div inside the 1st div, but max-height doesn't work.
   [image: The output should be like this]

```
<div style="height: 300px; top:10px;">
       <table>
       </table>
       <div style="top:50px; max-height:100px; overflow-y:scroll; position:relative;">
       <table>
       <tr>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </div>
       <div style="position:relative;">
        text here
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Missing a semicolon

Comment: I edit my post. It is not the real code. I just want to show the structure. Thanks by the way. @Vivick

Comment: By the way, I also tried to set height= calc(100% - 50px); on the inner div. but still doesn't work.

Comment: The table is empty, therefore the div is empty, you didn't set an actual height (`max-height` doesn't set the height) therefore the height is 0px

Comment: is `"height = 300px; top=10px;"` normal x) ? Same with "position=relative" these `=` should be `:`

Comment: yep, actually it's working on actual, but I can't get my desired output that if the contents of the inner div reached the max-height then the scroll-y will show. but then the max-height doesn't work. And when I set a height on the inner div, the div's height will be fixed, therefore the text shows not after the div, it will be after the height of the div. please refer to the image. Thank you for the comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this as being caused by typos, because the code shown works if you fix the CSS by changing all the `=` to `:`, and if you fix the HTML by closing the second `<table>` properly.

Comment: `overflow-y: auto` doesn't show the scrollbar if there's no need for scrolling and shows it if needed. You can use `min-height: /*some value here*/; height:auto;` too.

Comment: @nnnnnn it has nothing to do with the typos. The problem is the use of the different "tools" for height and overflow.

Comment: @Vivick - With the typos fixed it works: I'm not just hypothesising, I tried it for myself. If OP has some further issues beyond that they need to edit the question to fix the typos and then describe the problem in the question itself, not with comments that refer to other code not shown.

Comment: @exceptione May you, please, remove the javascript and jsp tags ? You might use them for your project but they are not part of the problem here.

Comment: Sorry for a lot of typos.

Answer (score 2):

Max height should work.  I'm not sure if the example you have is copied straight from your working code, but you didn't close the inner table.  Also setting the top on both shifted everything around kind of weird.  It'll be easier to look at your CSS if you move it into its own file.

```css
.Outer {
  height:300px;
 }
 
 .Inner {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  position: relative;
}

.Inner-Table {
  height: 200px;
}
.Relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="Outer">
  <table>
  </table>
  
  <div class="Inner">
    <table class="Inner-Table">
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1-1</td>
        <td>Cell 1-2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 2-1</td>
        <td>Cell 2-2</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Relative">
    text here
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Even though I hate using `px` for sizing, your solution is quite solid.

Comment: Thank you for this, yes I don`t actually copied my code. I just posted the structure. But the code you have posted is what actually my codes looks like. And max-height is not really working.

Comment: @exceptione Is the table actually large enough to cause an overflow?  max-height will expand/shrink like no height was set until it's large enough to hit the height specified.

Comment: I want to specify a maximum length for the inner div which contains a table, and when the max length was reached the scroll will be shown, and it's not working. I also tried to place the inner div outside to try if the max-length will work but it doesn't. If I set only a height, the div's height wouldn't be dynamic, and as a result the position of the text will display after the specified height not after the contents of the table.

Comment: And the text should always after the table. For short, I want the div's height be dynamic and once it reached it's max length the scroll will be shown. Thank you! I still can't find the answer why max-length doesn't work!